# В UITableView при прокрутке в ячейках констрейнты добавляются повторно

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Создал таблицу UITableViewController. В ней создаётся определённое количество ячеек. Они заполняются из массива. Ячейки кастомизированные. В каждой ячейке есть UIView. В функции `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` я добавляю констрейнт к этому UIView, задающий высоту. Если `picsCount` равен 0, то создаётся констрейнт с высотой 0, а если больше нуля, то со своей особой высотой.

```swift
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("postCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomPostCellTableViewCell
let picsCount = allposts[indexPath.row].pic.count
        print(picsCount)

        if picsCount > 0 {
            let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.viewVW, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100)
            cell.viewVW.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
        }
        else if picsCount == 0 {
            let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.viewVW, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
            cell.viewVW.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Когда я начинаю прокручивать этот список, то получается, что у одних ячеек нулевая высота, у других не нулевая. Причём нулевыми должны были идти первые ячейки, но этого не наблюдается, они в разнобой.

А также в дебаге выдаёт вот это:

```swift
2016-09-01 23:37:18.723 FriendDime[10039:2879999] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a78c9d0 V:[UIView:0x7a7a2890(100)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a69c730 V:[UIView:0x7a7a2890(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a78c9d0 V:[UIView:0x7a7a2890(100)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Я предполагаю, что ячейка повторно используется и констрейнт получается добавляется повторно. И выходит, что в некоторых ячейках получается по два констрейнта, один с нулевой высотой, а второй с высотой 100.

А ещё я хочу добавлять в этот UIView динамически картинки, количество которых будет разным в каждой ячейке. И что же это получается с картинками тоже будут такие проблемы?

Объясните как с этим справиться?

Comment: вы ж сами просите систему использовать заново имеющиеся ячейки через dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier. делайте removeConstraint если хотите его заменить на другой

Comment: А можно что-то другое использовать вместо dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, TableView (как и CollectionView) для экономии ресурсов при прокрутке использует одни и те же ячейки. Можете добавить `@property` c constraint's в наследнике класса ячейки, чтобы в методе `cellForRowAtIndexPath` не добавлять при каждой прокрутке новый, а изменять и инициализировать один единственный.

Еще можете посмотреть метод `prepareForReuse`, его нужно добавить в класс ячейки, в нем вызывайте `removeConstraint`.

p.s. для изменения высоты определенных ячеек можно использовать `tableview heightforrowatindexpath`

**UPD:**

removeConstraint удалит с вью один констрейнт, передаваемый в качестве аргумента. Еще можно использовать removeConstraints - в качестве аргумента передается массив констрейтов, который нужно удалить с вью.
 На swift можно сделать примерно так:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func prepareForReuse()
    {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        for heightConstraint in self.viewVW.constraints {

            if heightConstraint.firstAttribute == .Height {
                 self.viewVW.removeConstraint(heightConstraint)
            }

        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: По поводу tableview heightforrowatindexpath, у меня всё намного сложнее. У меня помимо UIView есть ещё другие элементы в ячейке. Там View Image для аватарки, заданный в интерфейс билдере, лейблы для имени пользователя и контента и всё это с констрентами. Высота ячейки и так меняется в зависимости от размера содержимого. Поэтому мне и пришлось использовать констрейнты для UIView, так как надо задавать ему строгую высоту.

Comment: Ещё вопрос по поводу removeConstraint. Если я это применю к UIView, то в нём удалятся все констрейнты, которые там были добавлены? А ещё я в этот UIView хочу добавлять картинки там же из кода. К примеру в одной ячейке будет 3 картинки, в другой 1. Их тоже можно будет так же удалить?

Comment: @cheerful_weasel добавил небольшой пример. Для удаления картинок  и вообще любых вью с экрана используйте метод removeFromSuperview.

Comment: к сожалению не сработало. Всё равно так же. Всё так же в дебаге для некоторых ячеек то сообщение выскакивает о том, что используются одновременно два констрейнта с разными высотами. 
А где использовать removeFromSuperview? Ну в смысле в какой части кода.

Comment: мм, а в метод заходит?

Comment: Вставил print для теста туда. Первый принт после super.prepareForReuse(), он в дебаге показывается, т.е. в метод входит. А второй принт поставил после self.removeConstraint(heightConstraint) и вот он в дебаге не отображается. Т.е. получается if не срабатывает

Comment: Дополнил пример. Удалять констрейнты нужно с вью на которую их добавляли.

Comment: Ругается там где for и пишет: Value of type 'CustomPostCellTableViewCell.TableViewCell' has no member 'viewVW' (мой класс для ячейки называется CustomPostCellTableViewCell)